# git revert and then how to update github?

Tags: git, github

so I followed the instruction to remove my last 4 commits at : [How to revert Git repository to a previous commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/revert-to-a-previous-git-commit)

After I do git reset --hard 0d1d7fc32

my git log does not show the last 4 commits but when I try to commit, it doesnt update my github

it says :
$ git commit .
On branch master
Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 4 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)

nothing to commit, working directory clean

how do i update my github so my last 4 commits are gone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> so my last 4 commits are gone?

```
git push origin master --force
```

It's not what you normally would like to do, but every tool is just a tool.

What this will do - it will move the `origin/master` branch pointer to the `0d1d7fc32`.